# str.split on page numbers

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm doing some simple text extraction of bibliographic data and have a string like so:

```
texts = '36 L. Ronse De Craene / Flora 221 (2016) 22–37Chen, L., Ren, Y., Endress, P.K., Tian, X.H., Zhang, X.H., 2007. Floral organogenesis inTetracentron sinense (Trochodendraceae) and its systematic signiﬁcance. PlantSyst. Evol. 264, 183–193.Choob, V.V., Yurtseva, O.V., 2007. Mathematical model of ﬂower formation in thePolygonaceae members. Bot. Zh. 92, 114–134.Clark, S.E., Running, M.P., Meyerowitz, E.M., 1993. CLAVATA1, a regulator ofmeristem and ﬂower development in Arabidopsis. Development 119, 397–418.Clark, S.E., Running, M.P., Meyerowitz, E.M., 1995. CLAVATA3 is a speciﬁc regulatorof shoot and ﬂoral meristem development affecting the same processes asCLAVATA1. Development 121, 2057–2067.Costello, A., Motley, T.J., 2004. The development of the superior ovary inTetraplasandra (Araliaceae). Am. J. Bot. 91, 644–655.Davidson, C., 1973. An anatomical and morphological study of Datiscaceae. Aliso 8,49–110.Dickison, W.C., 1990a. A study of the ﬂoral morphology and anatomy of theCaryocaraceae. Bull. Torrey Bot. Club 117, 123–137'
```

I would like to subset this string at page numbers which at the end of each entry are present in the form xxx-xxx where x is a digit so I figure something like this should work:

`re.split(r'\d+\-\d+', texts)`

I've tried a few variants of this but am unsuccessful. I don't use regex often and I think I'm missing something small.

Output I'm aiming for:

```
['36 L. Ronse De Craene / Flora 221 (2016)',

'Chen, L., Ren, Y., Endress, P.K., Tian, X.H., Zhang, X.H., 2007. Floral organogenesis inTetracentron sinense (Trochodendraceae) and its systematic signiﬁcance. PlantSyst. Evol. 264,',

'.Choob, V.V., Yurtseva, O.V., 2007. Mathematical model of ﬂower formation in thePolygonaceae members. Bot. Zh. 92,',  

...]
```

Comment: can you explain what output you want.?

Comment: A sample output or a pointer to where you want to split the string would be helpful.

Comment: test your regex form this link https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your – in your text string is different than that in your regex:

You could see it when you write one over the other:

-

–

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thank-you.